# React endless loop on 404

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mobx

I am working through a Udemy course on react, and I am facing a strange issue when it comes to what happens when I try to load an activity that doesn't exist if I do it via the URL (this is because our UI will obviously not render invalid activities). I did verify that my `useEffect` properly defines its dependencies in order to not cause an infinite loop that it normally would as so:

```
useEffect(() => {
      console.log("Params id: ", match.params.id);
      loadActivity(match.params.id)
    }, [loadActivity, match.params.id, history])
```

Where the component in question has the following signature `const ActivityDetails : React.FC<RouteComponentProps<DetailParams>>` When I look at the console logs I can see that this use effect is hit all the time, interestingly though, so is its render return (within the same component) for what happens when it has no activity to return

```
if(!activity) {
  console.log("not activity");
  return <h2>Not Found</h2>
}
```

The path for it is defined in its parent container as follows:

```
 <Route key={location.key} path={['/createActivity', '/manage/:id']}
```

The MobX action is defined as such:

```
@action loadActivity = async (id: string) => {
    let activity = this.getActivity(id);
    console.log("activity is: ", activity);
    if (activity !== undefined) {
      this.activity = activity;
    } else {
      console.log("activity is undefined");
      this.loadingInitial = true;
      try {
        activity = await agent.Activities.details(id);
        console.log("after wait, acitivty is:", activity);
        runInAction('getting activity',() => {
          console.log("Now i am running the next run in action");
          this.activity = activity;
          this.loadingInitial = false;
        })
      } catch (error) {
        runInAction('get activity error', () => {
          this.loadingInitial = false;
        })
        console.log("Error Is: ", error);
      }
    }
  }
```

And the Agent where we get our activity looks as follows:

```
const responseBody = (response: AxiosResponse ) => response.data;
const requests = {
    get : (url: string) => axios.get(url).then(responseBody),
    ...
}

const Activities = {
    details: (id: string) => requests.get(`/activities/detail/${id}`),
    ...
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Edit: I am not sure if this is part of the react life cycle, but it looks like when I refresh that page, the if(!activity) render is fired, but of course we don't see it since it quickly finds an activity to render. My understanding of useEffect is that it is supposed to fire first before the component is mounted, defines the states there, and then the life cycle goes on?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, still unsure as to why, but moving the code that loads the initial activities from the Activities.tsx file (aka the overall parent) to the Dashboard code (which is also defined there as `Route exact path='/activities' component={ActivityDashboard}/>` seems to fix the issue.

Could someone please explain why? Is it a pathing issue? I was under the impression that using the `exact` keyword would only work if the path was an exact match